# Option[String] vs String that may be empty in Scala

Tags: string, scala

I have a field where the user may enter a description that is passed on to a client. The user may also choose to leave this field empty.

My question is what's the best way of reprecenting this? A String that may be empty? Or an Option[String] that has the value none when the user decides not to write anything in this particular field?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case. Do you want to differentiate between the following two cases:

- Description is an empty string
- Description doesn't exist

In my experience, there were often use cases where the two were considered equivalent, but later turned out to be different. For example, protobuf had a lot of back-and-forth with this, forcing people to go from `String` to `com.google.protobuf.StringValue` (or, using proto3, `optional string`) to be able to differentiate empty string from null / no value.

So if you're in doubt, you're probably better off having `Option[String]` and doing `description.getOrElse("")` on the consumer side, knowing that your API has the doors open for future scenarios where you need that distinction, instead of having to modify the API later with possibly backwards incompatible changes).

Even if you're just modeling your code and you know you'll be sending an empty string across the wire, it's still a good design. Once you lump "empty string" and "no string" into the same data representation, there's no way of figuring out which case you had. Unless you have a domain where those two really are equivalent, e.g. leaving a blank (empty string) "middle name" is equal to not having a middle name.

Comment: In my case description is a field in an entity called "requirements". When creating a "requirements" the user have several fileds to fill in. A few of the multiple select fields are mandatory, but most fileds are optional.

Comment: The user will always have the option to type something in the description field, or not.   I can't see a way to difreanciate between the description filed not existing and the descripotion field beeing empty as the user will always be given the option to type something, but may decide not to. After the user has created the "requirements" it is shown in a tabe with a column for description that may contain text or be empty.

Comment: Is Option[String] a good way of indication that it is optinal for the user to type something in this field?

Does the consept of a mandatory string field even make sense when the user could just type some placeholder character like a space to get around any such restrictions?

Comment: I would split this into two parts, first I would receive just a plain `String`. And then parse that into an ADT that properly models all the know states.